# Android notification not fired when app killed

Tags: android

I am using alarm manager to set the time and fire a notification at that particular time. Works fine when app is foreground or background. I am testing on Android 8. However my problem is when app is killed from task manager, the notification is not fired because the broadcast does not work. This is because I register receiver in onCreate() of MainActivity and unregister receiver in onDestroy(). Maybe it would work if I register my broadcast receiver in manifest but it is not allowed from Android 8 onwards. How do I address this problem that I receive the broadcast even when app is killed?

Comment: You should make a service and start it whenever the phone has been booted up or your app has, you can keep this service alive even if your app has been killed.
check out how broadcast receiver works.

Comment: Thank you, could you give me a pseudo code or an example of how it can be implemented or some links. That would be helpful

Comment: If im not mistaken i have an old project with a working broadcast receiver that notifies you whenever your localization is near a spot. ill try to find that later tonight and ill let you know if i do find it.

Comment: That would be great:) thank you

Comment: Quick thing you should check, i saw your last question, why would you stop your broadcast receiver onDestroy of your app if you want to destroy it whenever the user has already received the alarm, you should instead stop the service whenever the notification has been sent.

Comment: I try to register my receiver now on alarm manager set and unregister it when I receive broadcast from alarm manager and i notify. However this seems to work for Android O but not Android 5 version. How can i register for Android 5 devices?

Answer (score 1):

BroadCastREceiver Example

```js
public class SchedulerMailBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Log.i("scheduler: " + new DateWrapper().getLocaleString());
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = null;
            if (pm != null) {
                Log.d("aquire wakelog");
                wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "ics:mailScheduler");
                wl.acquire(10000);
            }
            startInNewThread(context.getApplicationContext(),wl);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(e);
        }
    }
    public void startInNewThread(final Context context, PowerManager.WakeLock wl){
        new ThreadWrapper(() -> {
            try {
               //Do Stuff
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(e);
            }finally {
                Log.d("releasing wakelog");
                try {
                    wl.release();
                    Log.i("released wakelog");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("wakelog release","exception on releasing wawkelog");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static boolean registerScheduler(Context context){

        final int requestCode=1234;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SchedulerMailBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("startScheduler");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
           // alarmManager.cancel(previousPendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000 * 60*15, pendingIntent);
            Log.i("registered repeating");
        }
        return  true;
    }


}
```

you probably dont want setRepeating though

JobService example

```js
public class SchedulerMailJobManager extends JobService{

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        try {
            Log.i("SchedulerMailJobManager","scheduler run at "+ new DateWrapper().getLocaleString());
            startInNewThread(getApplicationContext(),params);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("SchedulerMailJobManager","errpr in starting new thread",e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ServiceRestarter.class);
        intent.setAction("restartService");
        intent.putExtra("service","mailScheduler");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.w("stoppedJob","stopped");
        return true;
    }

    public void startInNewThread(final Context context,final JobParameters params){
        new ThreadWrapper(() -> {
            try {
                //Do Stuff
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("JobScheduler2ndThread","Exception",e);
            }finally {
                if(params!=null) {
                    this.jobFinished(params,false);
                }else{
                    Log.e("JobScheduler2ndThread","no params for jobFinished");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


    static JobInfo createScheduledJob(Context context){
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context,SchedulerMailJobManager.class );
        JobInfo.Builder builder=new JobInfo.Builder(1234,serviceComponent);
        int waitMin=30;
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        builder.setPersisted(true);
        builder.setPeriodic(1000*60*waitMin,1000);
        return builder.build();
    }
    public static boolean registerScheduler(Context context){
        JobScheduler scheduler=context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        if(scheduler==null){
            Log.e("registerScheduler","scheduler is null");
            return false;
        }
        if(scheduler.getPendingJob(1234)!=null) {
            scheduler.cancel(1234);
            Log.i("registerScheduler","cancelled previous");
        }
        int resultCode=scheduler.schedule(createScheduledJob(context));
        if(resultCode==JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS){
            Log.i("JobManagerScheduler","registered new scheduler");
            return true;
        }else{
            Log.e("registerScheduler","failed registering");
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

since you only have a Notification you probably dont need to start anything in a new thread which means in this solution you should return false in OnStartJob